# How to get an attribute inside a Iframe windows selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I'm facing a problem when I could not get a attribute in site a iframe windows, the iframe doesn't have an id or any thing so I would find it by the title

Here's my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
import os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_driver():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\ProjectProfile\\test\\1")
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    options.set_capability("pageLoadStrategy", "eager")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    return driver
driver = get_driver()
driver.get("https://losangeles.craigslist.org/sfv/atq/d/oak-park-1926-antique-radio-atwater/7703300207.html")
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "printme"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(element_present)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//section/header/div[2]/div/button").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='Main content of the hCaptcha challenge']"))
src = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='Main content of the hCaptcha challenge']").get_attribute("src")
print(src)
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong?

My goals was get the "src" attribute inside this HTML tag:

```
<iframe src="./Golf cart gas - atvs, utvs, snowmobiles - by owner - vehicle automotive sale - craigslist_files/hcaptcha.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allow="private-state-token-issuance 'src'; private-state-token-redemption 'src'" title="Main content of the hCaptcha challenge" style="border: 0px; z-index: 2000000000; position: relative; width: 400px; height: 600px;"></iframe>
```

Here is the site source: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XuZq_oUftC9llaU607fnLPk2p_M5Mrwy/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to switch to iframe to get attribute of iframe webelement. If element is inside iframe then only you need to switch to frame. Currently element is at outside of frame hence we directly use get attribute of iFrame element.

```
driver = get_driver()
driver.get("https://losangeles.craigslist.org/sfv/atq/d/oak-park-1926-antique-radio-atwater/7703300207.html")
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "printme"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(element_present)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//section/header/div[2]/div/button").click()
time.sleep(5)
src = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='Main content of the hCaptcha challenge']").get_attribute("src")
print(src)
```